# How to use a variable in a filepath?

Tags: java, csv, foreach

I have a program that takes monthly data as input from a file and outputs numbers based on a criteria (ex: filtering out numbers less than 100). However, I want my program to automatically do it for 3 months (march, april, may). How do I make the filepath in which my output is saved variable?

```
public class Testing2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String[] month = new String[]{march,april,may};
        for(String s: month){
            File f=new File("C:\\java\\marchcall.csv");
            FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter("C:\\java\\marchcallnew.csv");
            Scanner in=new Scanner(f).useDelimiter(",");
        }
    }
}
```

I want my program to take numbers from 3 different files marchcall.csv, aprilcall.csv and maycall.csv and output after running the program to marchcallnew.csv, aprilcallnew.csv and maycallnew.csv.

I thought of using a foreach loop but I'm not quite sure how to make the filepath variable (if that's the correct term).

Comment: those file paths are just strings. `new FileWrite('C:\\java\\' + somestringvar + '.csv');`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the string elements are *not* variable names, your code will not compile. The string elements must be surrounded by quotes. After this error is fixed, you can read all three files  like this:

```
String[] month = new String[]{"march", "april", "may"};   //Must have quotes!
for(String s: month){
   File f=new File("C:\\java\\" + s + "call.csv");
   FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter("C:\\java\\" + s + "callnew.csv");

   //do stuff in the file
```

Also, you may want to consider renaming your `month` variable to `monthArr` or `months` to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

To get each string from the array with the for each loop you will want to do the following:

```
String[] months = new String[]{"march","april","may"}; //Make sure your strings are surrounded by quotes. You will get an error for this otherwise.

for(String month: months){

  File f = new File("C:\\java\\" + month + "call.csv");
  FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter("C:\\java\\" + month + "callnew.csv");
```

It is as easy as that. When you are creating your new file it will append the current month from the for each loop into the file name string.

Comment: @aliteralmind Haha, I had not finished my answer and there was no answer before. You win this round good sir!

Comment: Until our next smackdown  :)